# What does HIDDEN and PROVIDE_HIDDEN in linker scripts exactly do?

Tags: linker, linker-scripts

I have gone through the linker documentation for [HIDDEN](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/HIDDEN.html#HIDDEN) and [PROVIDE_HIDDEN](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/PROVIDE_005fHIDDEN.html#PROVIDE_005fHIDDEN) multiple times, but I am not really able to understand what they exactly do.

For example, if I write a linker script with an assignment like this :

```
naveen = 10;
SECTIONS
  {

  }
```

I see the symbol in

```
$ objdump -t kernel8.elf  | grep naveen
000000000000000a g       *ABS*  0000000000000000 naveen
```

If I add `HIDDEN`, I still see the symbol there :

```
HIDDEN(naveen = 10);
SECTIONS
  {
  }

$ objdump -t kernel8.elf  | grep naveen
000000000000000a l       *ABS*  0000000000000000 naveen
```

For `PROVIDE` and `PROVIDE_HIDDEN` added in `SECTIONS` command, I don't see the symbol in either case. So I am not really able to differentiate between `HIDDEN/non-hidden` and `PROVIDE/PROVIDE_HIDDEN` behaviours. Can someone please explain with nice and short example the use-cases. I searched a lot but either I did not find good examples, or I could not make sense out of it.

Comment: Notice the flag changed from `g` to `l`. As for `PROVIDE` the manual says _"The PROVIDE keyword may be used to define a symbol, such as ‘etext’, only if it is referenced but not defined. "_. So you will only see it if you reference it somewhere.

Comment: Oh I missed that. So the documentation also said that in case of `HIDDEN`, none of the symbols will be visible outside the current module. So what's `module` here ? Is the module referring to the current output file/executable being linked? Then it makes sense.

Comment: The current file, yes.

Comment: I may be missing something but I still don't understand the behaviour of PROVIDE_HIDDEN...